# Перейти на другую страницу в React при нажатии на компоненту

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, frontend, redirect

такой вопрос. Я хочу что-бы при нажатии на компоненту открывалась новая страница, например википедия. Пробовал повесить на компоненту:

```
onClick={()=>{
return  <Redirect to={link}/>
}}
```

но это что-то не то. Кто знает как можно сделать это, именно при клике?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы открывалась новая страница (не редирект) можно написать так:

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => window.open("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/")}>
        Link
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: У меня проблема в том что нет возможности поставить  в <a></a> компоненту.  Мне нужно именно через onClick сделать

Comment: Откорректировал  ответ